# Problem in subcommands of the Bash Script

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, sh

I had the bash script where in I had to launch the application ide command and then the >>> appears in the terminal where in I had to execute the commands such as in script file
#!/bin/bash

OMShell-terminal

loadModel(Modelica)

loadFile("Filename")

simulate(filename, startTime, stopTime)

but after loading the OMShell-terminal I will get the >>>to input the commands here but the shell script would not let me to input the commands here from shell script itself what modification I should do please guide.

Comment: Can you send the commands to the stdin of the application?

Comment: OMShell-terminal

loadModel(Modelica)

loadFile("Filename")

simulate(filename, startTime, stopTime) these are the commands

Comment: In other words, does `echo 'loadModel(Modelica)' | OMShell-terminal` run the command in the application?

Comment: Can you please help how to add the subcommands when the command ide starts with >>> such as if I want to run python in bash script and input the commands into >>> from bash script itself then how to do? Iam new to bash script Please help

Comment: The `|` pipe redirects the output of `echo` to the standard input of the terminal. See "REDIRECTION" in `man bash`.

Comment: Yes it is working but for only one echo statement but if I want to give the other 2 commands how should I give?

Comment: E.g. `printf '%s\n' 'loadModel(Modelica)' 'loadFile("Filename")' ... | OMShell-terminal`